# How to configure a tor proxy on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tor, socks

How do I configure a [tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/installguide.html.en) proxy on windows?

For example, I want to run the following python script through a tor proxy:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http':'socks5h://localhost:9050',
    'https':'socks5h:/localhost:9050'
}
url = 'someWebsite.onion'
res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

On unix systems, you can simply run `tor` in terminal, but this doesn't seem to work on windows.

Answer (score 8):

navigate to `\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor` and edit torcc file

```
# ControlPort 9051
SocksPort 9051
```

Then restart tor.

#### Use tor proxy everywhere:

control panel -> network & internet -> internet options -> connection -> lan setting -> tick proxy server & goto advance & add:

```
proxy 127.0.0.1 port 9051
```

#### Use tor proxy in a browser like firefox:

options -> network setting -> tick Manual proxy configuration & add:

```
proxy 127.0.0.1 port 9051
```

#### Use with Python requests library:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http':'socks5://127.0.0.1:9051',
    'https':'socks5:/127.0.0.1:9051'
}
url = 'https://check.torproject.org/'
res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

**Note: You have to keep running tor browser for this**

Comment: I had to launch tor at least once and connect before I saw the torcc file. This works perfect.

Comment: Just fix your python code, "socks5h" instead o "socks5" in the proxy settings.

Answer (score 3):

[Txtorcon](https://txtorcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html) and [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/index.html) are libraries developed by the Tor Project for controlling Tor from Python. Stem doesn't have any external dependencies. However, txtorcon allows one to launch Tor from Python, rather than just connect to a running instance.

Both of these libraries require a Tor binary already installed though. It is possible to use the Tor included with the Tor Browser Bundle, connecting on port 9150 (with control port of 9151).

Better yet though, you can download the "Expert Bundle" to get the Tor binary without any browser. The download for it is not currently linked from their new website, but the latest version can still be pulled from https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/. Navigate to a directory for either the alpha or stable version and search for "tor-win64-" (or "tor-win32-" if you need 32-bit).

Answer (score 3):

he working good, but need start tor service in windows
or made service tor auto start in windows when startup

all time tor service in this path after download tor browser

`your_installation_path\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor`

the bin name is tor.exe you should add path in the windows PATH