# Facing problem in Configuring Tor to hash a new password in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, hash, tor

I have tried and read various articles over the internet about hashing a new password for Tor.
My tor is installed in local disk D
I used the following commands in the command prompt

```
D:\softwares\tor\Tor Browser\Browser>firefox --hash-password <my password> | more
D:\softwares\tor\Tor Browser\Browser>firefox --hash-password <my password> > tor-password.txt
```

to get the output of the hashed password but there is no o/p of the hashed password instead the command is prompting to open the Tor browser. And the text file in the location is also empty.
I noticed that my tor application name was firefox.exe in the installed location but it created a shortcut named tor on the desktop.
After getting my hashed password I am intending to use it in torrc ( TOR configuration file) to
Update the “ControlPort” listener for TOR to listen on port 9051, as this is the port to which TOR                        will listen for any communication from applications talking to the Tor controller,
Update the hashed password and to
Implement cookie authentication

I am following the below articles to build a web scraper.
[How to scrape websites without getting blocked](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/)  and
[How To Make Anonymous Requests using TorRequests and Python](https://www.scrapehero.com/make-anonymous-requests-using-tor-python/)

Please mention if I can provide any further details.

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:python] and [tag:web-scraping], but your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. It might be a better fit on [su].

Comment: @Chris sure will update there. I really appreciate it for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, I went to the directory where I had the installed application but I had to look into the bin name is tor.exe at `your_installation_path\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor`
and execute the command `D:\softwares\tor\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor>tor.exe --hash-password <my password> | more`
follow this answer for clarification
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612997/10990865